# How to get more info about the boot message "Waiting for /dev to be fully populated"

Tags: debian, boot, logs

during the boot of my Debian I see

> Waiting for /dev to be fully populated

and then a timeout expires, the text is rapidly scrolling and so I cannot read it; the boot process continue with no errors.

I would like to read the logs in order to find some more information: I have tried the program "system log viewer" but I cannot find the string "populated" nor in `message` nor in `syslog`.

Comment: I remember having to enable logging (recording to a file) for the boot log. When I had a problem. I can not remember how.

Comment: I don't remember where that is off the top of my head but try `grep -R populated /var/log`.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Debian, and which init system are you using?  With new systemd, use `journalctl -b` or follow [this instruction](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/).  With old traditional sysvinit, you can use [bootlogd](https://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd) to log all the output from init scripts.

I can see that message in `/etc/init.d/udev`, which would be run by sysvinit boot.

```
    # wait for the udevd childs to finish
    log_action_begin_msg "Waiting for /dev to be fully populated"
    if udevadm settle; then
        log_action_end_msg 0
    else
        log_action_end_msg 0 'timeout'
    fi
```

If you see this 'timeout' message, that would mean you have some devices in the system for udev to take a long time to probe.  You might want to investigate the problem by manually running `udevadm settle`.