# At boot time, "Waiting for /dev to be fully populated" forces a reboot

Tags: debian, linux-mint

I run Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE2, Debian 8.1). All updates are installed.

About 50% of the time I boot my laptop, it crashes and forces an immediate reboot. The message I last got from the console before the reboot is

```
Waiting for /dev to be fully populated
```

Is there a way to get more details on what could have cause the reboot? Or are there any known issues?

Here's my laptop details:

[https://www.amazon.com/GL551-15-inch-Gaming-Laptiop-Model/dp/B00T7XRH2A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T7XRH2A)

---

**What I know so far:**

Booting via recovery option significantly reduces but does not eliminate the possibility of the crash.

I tried google around and couldn't find anything helpful. I looked at

[How to get more info about the boot message "Waiting for /dev to be fully populated"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212702/how-to-get-more-info-about-the-boot-message-waiting-for-dev-to-be-fully-popula)

and /var/log/boot doesn't exist.

There's a few posts about hanging/timeouts, which is not exactly what I look for.

I tried disable a few things in the BIOS (wake on lan, touchpad, USB compatibility mode, etc).

Some posts mention nVidia optimus, but there's no option to disable it in the BIOS.

Comment: On AntiX linux (Debian based), this happened on a ~2006 Pentium 4 Dell unless I forced 1280x1024 video out. `video=1280x1024` in GRUB.